# What are sufficient conditions for a vector field to be a multiple of a gradient?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, vector-fields

Given a vector field $\vec{v}(x)$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$, with standard euclidian metric, you can asociate a 1-form $\tilde{\omega}$ and the question of when you can write the vector field as:
$$
\vec{v}= f \, \vec{\nabla}\phi
$$
for some functions $f$ and $\phi$, is equivalent to writing the 1-form as:
$$
\tilde{\omega} = g \, d\psi
$$ 
for some functions $g$ and $\psi$. All functions from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

I know that a $\textit{necessary}$ condition is $\vec{v} \cdot \vec{\nabla}\times \vec{v}=0$ which is equivalent to $\tilde{\omega} \, \wedge \, d \tilde{\omega}=0$

Now I was reading the forum and came across this question:

[How does an integrating factor geometrically "uncurl" a vector field?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57488/how-does-an-integrating-factor-geometrically-uncurl-a-vector-field)

And in two of the answers they claim that it is also a $\textit{sufficient}$ condition as a corollary of Frobenius' theorem. I must confess that I am not very familiar with that theorem, but that result seems so counter intuitive and wrong (to me) as some examples may ilustrate:

Consider $\textit{any}$ two-dimensional vector field, for example $\vec{v}(x,y,z)= (-x-y,x-y,0)$ (spirals) then it follows that the curl is always pointing in the $z$-direction. And therefore  $\vec{v} \cdot \vec{\nabla}\times \vec{v}=0$, so according to the condition I should be able to write $\vec{v}=f\, \vec{\nabla}\phi$. But consider the orthogonal vector field $\vec{w}(x,y,z)= (x-y, x+y,0)$ (also spirals) the solutions to that vector field parametrize the level-curves of $\phi$, but the level-curves "approach" the origin and that never happens with level-curves. So, what just happen?

Perhaps the problems is that $\vec{v}(0,0,0)= \vec{0}$ and the $\textit{sufficient}$ condition also needs that the vector field is not equal to zero in an open set or something like that. (Something like a foliation I imagine).

My question is where have I gone wrong about Frobenius' theorem? Is that really the (necessary)-sufficient condition? Or under what circumstances I can write a vector/ 1-form as multiple of a gradient? It is also equivalent to when a integral-factor exist. Is there a stronger condition that does not require the vector field to be different from zero? If someone could also recommend a place where I can read Frobenius' theorem in a not-very-advance level I would appreciate it as I am fairly new to differential-forms.

Thank you :)

Comment: The confusion is that the Frobenius theorem is a local statement, in the same way that closedness of a form is sufficient conditions for him to locally be exact.  Indeed, the vector field $ (-x-y, x-y,0) / (x^2 + y^2)  $ is _locally_  the gradient of the angle function.